# How to get a <list> from mvc controller to view using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to get a list from mvc controller to view using jquery ajax. But I get  `[object Object]`.

**Ajax code**

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: '/Home/getList',                        
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                $scope.StuList = data;
                alert(data);                                
            }
        });
```

**In Controller**

```
    public JsonResult getList()
    {
       Models.clsSave obj = new Models.clsSave();    
       var list = new List<Model>();
       list= obj.getList();
       return Json(list,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `alert(data)` use `console.dir(data)` and look in the browser console window.  The alert window will only give you a type (in this case object) unless it's a simple type (string/int etc).

Comment: The answer is that you are already getting the data as a list, but looking at it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting [Object,Object] means it contains the data. You just Iterate it on the success function of your $.ajax as shown below

```
success: function (data) {
$.each(data.items, function(item) {
            alert('id :'item.id +' Name:'+item.sname);
            });
}
```

All the best

Comment: `$.each(data, function (i, item)` This is whats worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an Object from ajax response to view that in alert try to stingify your object:
`alert(JSON.stringify(data))`

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get a list from mvc controller to view using jquery ajax.
>   But I get [object Object].

that means you're getting correct data list

> how will I store it in $scope.StuList

You can just assign that `data` to `$scope.StuList`.

```
$scope.StuList = data;
```

Just to verify your data, put it in iteration

```
$.each($scope.StuList,function(i,v){
  alert(v.sname);
});
```

You should get the correct data.

Or you can also put it in console, and verify yourself.

```
console.log($scope.StuList)
```

Hope this will help, or let me know if you still facing any issue.